# Pinning and unpinning elements on scroll with Framer Motion (ScrollTrigger)

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, scrolltrigger

I am new to Framer Motion and I am trying to recreate ScrollTrigger's functionality of pinning and unpinning elements on scroll. In the example I have working, the box unpins when component `<Two />` enters the viewport, but when you scroll back up to re-pin it, you get a slight stutter, even with the layout parameter set.

Is there a better way to do this with Framer Motion?

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-pin-element-lzmvq8?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slight stutter you're experiencing when scrolling back up to re-pin the box is likely due to the way you're updating the position of the box with top: `pinBox` && `scrollY`. This expression is causing the box to jump to the current scroll position whenever `pinBox` changes from `false` to `true`. You can use `useTransform` hook in this kind of situation.

```js
 const { scrollY } = useScroll();
 const [pinBox, setPinBox] = useState(true);

 const boxY = useTransform(
    scrollY,
    [0, window.innerHeight],
    [0, window.innerHeight]
  );
```

And apply following changes inside `motion.div` component's `style` prop

```js
<motion.div
        layout
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: pinBox ? boxY : "auto",
          bottom: pinBox ? "auto" : 0,
          left: "50%",
          width: "100px",
          height: "100px",
          backgroundColor: "red",
          x: "-50%"
        }}
      />
```

This should fix the stutter.